# How to set array B[0..n][0..k]. Help Please

Tags: c, arrays

I have to implement code to find the **Binomial Coefficient** using dynamic programming. But I don't know how to set the array B. Here the code I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int minimum(int a, int b) { return (a < b) ? a : b; }

main() {
    int n = 50, k;
    printf("Enter value for k:");
    scanf("%d", &k);
    printf("Value of coefficient %d, %d is: %d\n", n, k, bin2(n, k));

    return 0;
}

// code to be implemented

int bin2(int n, int k) {
    int i, j;

    // array to initialize. Help
    int B[0..n][0..k];

    for (i = 0; i <= n; i++)
        for (j = 0; j <= minimum(i, k); j++)
            if (j == 0 || j == i)
                B[i][j] = 1;
            else
                B[i][j] = B[i - 1][j - 1] + B[i - 1][j];
    return B[n][k];
}
```

Comment: `int B[n][k];` could be the declaration and your for Loops should only go till `i<n` and `j<minimum(i,k)`

Comment: Related: Even if you manage to fix the declaration of `B` you're code will invoke *undefined behavior* as it runs one element *past* the last addressable slot on both the `i` and `j` dimensions. C arrays are zero-base-indexed. Ex: `int A[N]` is indexible from `A[0]` thru `A[N-1]`.

Comment: Thanks @mch it just outputs whatever value k is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `malloc()` and `calloc()` functions from `<stdlib.h>` to allocate memory on the fly. Since you want to be able to store indices from 0 to n and 0 to k, you have to create a (n+1) × (k+1) array. This is done by allocating an array of n+1 `int*` pointers, then assigning an array of k+1 `int` values to each pointer:

```
    /* Initialize array */
    B = malloc((n+1) * sizeof(int*));
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) B[i] = calloc((k+1), sizeof(int));
```

When your function exits, this memory will still be allocated, but you will no longer be able to access it because the value of `B` is local to the `bin2()` function and will be lost forever. (This is called a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak).)

So you need to free up this memory before returning:

```
    int result = B[n][k];

    /* Dispose of array */
    for (i=0; i<=n; i++) free(B[i]);
    free(B);

    return result;
}
```

(By the way, this isn't [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) you're asking about, it's [dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#Dynamic_memory_allocation). And there are [better ways of calculating binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Computing_the_value_of_binomial_coefficients).)